# Issues getting the y-values form my Singleton to my graph

Tags: ios, swift, input, graph, singleton

This is the first graph I am trying to graph. I have three variables saved in a Singleton, they come from three sliders. I have 7 y-values I calculate from my variables in the singleton.

I would like to use the y-values in the graph, but I don't seem to load them in to the graphPoints correctly. I have tried everything I could find online during the last couple of weeks...

**These are my errors:**

> Value of type 'GraphView' has no member 'graphPoints'
>
> Value of type 'Double' has no member 'maxElement'
>
> Type 'Double' has no subscript member
>
> Value of type 'Double' has no member 'count'

**This is my code:**

```
//import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GraphView: UIView {

    //1 - the properties for the gradient

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()

    @IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let width = rect.width
        let height = rect.height

        //set up background clipping area
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect,
                                byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.AllCorners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0))
        path.addClip()

        //2 - get the current context
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let colors = [startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor]

        //3 - set up the color space
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        //4 - set up the color stops
        let colorLocations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

        //5 - create the gradient
        let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace,
                                                  colors,
                                                  colorLocations)

        //6 - draw the gradient
        var startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        var endPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.bounds.height)
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context,gradient,startPoint,endPoint, CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))



        // y-values

        var y1 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*1)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)
        var y2 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*2)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)
        var y3 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*3)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)
        var y4 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*4)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)
        var y5 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*5)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)
        var y6 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*6)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)
        var y7 = (Singleton.sharedInstance.varA)*exp((-Singleton.sharedInstance.vara*7)/Singleton.sharedInstance.varD)

        var yPoints = [Double]()

        yPoints.append(y1)
        yPoints.append(y2)
        yPoints.append(y3)
        yPoints.append(y4)
        yPoints.append(y5)
        yPoints.append(y6)
        yPoints += [y7]

        var graphPoints = yPoints [0]



        //calculate the x point

        let margin:CGFloat = 20.0
        let columnXPoint = { (column:Int) -> CGFloat in
            //Calculate gap between points
            let spacer = (width - margin*2 - 4) /
                CGFloat((self.graphPoints.count - 1))
            var x:CGFloat = CGFloat(column) * spacer
            x += margin + 2
            return x
        }



        // calculate the y point

        let topBorder:CGFloat = 60
        let bottomBorder:CGFloat = 50
        let graphHeight = height - topBorder - bottomBorder
        let maxValue = graphPoints.maxElement()!
        let columnYPoint = { (graphPoint:Double) -> CGFloat in
            var y:CGFloat = CGFloat(graphPoint) /
                CGFloat(maxValue) * graphHeight
            y = graphHeight + topBorder - y // Flip the graph
            return y
        }

        // draw the line graph

        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()

        //set up the points line
        let graphPath = UIBezierPath()
        //go to start of line
        graphPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(0),
            y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[0])))

        //add points for each item in the graphPoints array
        //at the correct (x, y) for the point
        for i in 1..<graphPoints.count {
            let nextPoint = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i),
                                    y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[i]))
            graphPath.addLineToPoint(nextPoint)
        }

        //Create the clipping path for the graph gradient

        //1 - save the state of the context (commented out for now)
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        //2 - make a copy of the path
       let clippingPath = graphPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath

        //3 - add lines to the copied path to complete the clip area
        clippingPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
            x: columnXPoint(graphPoints.count - 1),
            y:height))
        clippingPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
            x:columnXPoint(0),
            y:height))
        clippingPath.closePath()

        //4 - add the clipping path to the context
        clippingPath.addClip()

        //5 - check clipping path - temporary code
        UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
        let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        rectPath.fill()
        //end temporary code

        let highestYPoint = columnYPoint(maxValue)
        startPoint = CGPoint(x:margin, y: highestYPoint)
        endPoint = CGPoint(x:margin, y:self.bounds.height)

       CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, [])
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)

        //draw the line on top of the clipped gradient
        graphPath.lineWidth = 2.0
        graphPath.stroke()


        //Draw the circles on top of graph stroke
        for i in 0..<graphPoints.count {
            var point = CGPoint(x:columnXPoint(i), y:columnYPoint(graphPoints[Double]))
            point.x -= 5.0/2
            point.y -= 5.0/2

            let circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:
                CGRect(origin: point,
                    size: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)))
            circle.fill()

            //Draw horizontal graph lines on the top of everything
            let linePath = UIBezierPath()

            //top line
            linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:margin, y: topBorder))
            linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width - margin,
                y:topBorder))

            //center line
            linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:margin,
                y: graphHeight/2 + topBorder))
            linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:width - margin,
                y:graphHeight/2 + topBorder))

            //bottom line
            linePath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x:margin,
                y:height - bottomBorder))
            linePath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:width - margin,
                y:height - bottomBorder))
            let color = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)
            color.setStroke()

            linePath.lineWidth = 1.0
            linePath.stroke()
        }

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Graphpoints isn't a member variable of your class, its a local variable of the drawRect method. Move its declaration out of the function and into the top of the class

```
@IBDesignable class GraphView: UIView {
var graphPoints =  [Double]()
...
```

Or if you don't need to use it outside of drawRect() then keep it there but
change `self.graphPoints` to be just `graphPoints` when you use it.

Secondly graphPoints is not an array, its a Double. 
This is where you create it " `var graphPoints = yPoints [0]`".  If yPoints is an array of doubles, then yPoints[0] is just a double and therefore you are assigning a double to graphPoints and therefore the type of graphPoints is a double.